# Copy formulas with XLWings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm running into a headache-inducing issue, relating to **copying formulas upwards for an entire row.** I am using `xlwings` in Python.
I'm hoping you can help!

| Index | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 | FFFFF | =A3 |

Given the above table, I need to copy the **values** and **formulas** from the first row that happens to have a value in column B (row 3 in this example), insert them into the newly inserted row 1 but keep the formula relative (**this is the bit that is killing me**)

| Index | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **FFFF** | **=A1** |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 | FFFF | =A3 |

Can anyone help?

**EDIT**
Per @FelixZumstein's answer, this is the code that fulfilled my needs:

```
self.ws.range("1:1").insert("down", "format_from_right_or_below")

# Copy the original row to the newly inserted one
self.ws.range("3:3").copy()
self.ws.range("1:1").paste(paste="formulas")
```

Comment: I think you can use the literal copy/paste command for this: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Range.copy and https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Range.paste

Comment: @FelixZumstein Nice, that worked perfectly! Thanks!